# PHP- Maintain leading 0 in number

Tags: php

I have stock numbers that may contain a leading 0. For example:

```
0550
0551
0552
```

In efforts to find the next stock number, I do some simple addition:

```
$stock = '0552'; // This is found by querying the database

$nextstock = $stock + 1;
```

The problem is, `$newstock` returns `553`- it removes the leading 0.

And I can't simply do something like this:

```
$nextstock = '0'.($stock + 1);
```

because not all the stock numbers will have leading zeros.

So, how do I increment a number that contains a leading 0 by 1 without removing the leading 0 and without forcing a leading 0 onto the variable, since they may not all have leading zeros?

Comment: Are all numbers always 4 digits in length?

Comment: @SetSailMedia No, I have thousands of items, so the digits are not always 4 characters long

Comment: [sprint()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), [str_pad()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

Comment: my ugly answer for what its worth:http://ideone.com/tza21l

Comment: @Dagon Don't mind my last comment. Now I see what you mean with *ugly* :) (Would never thought about this way to do it)

Comment: oh i missed it was it nasty? :-) - all good bro